# What events can a user see in Salesforce

Tags: security, permissions, event, calendar

When looking at the Calendar/Events page, I'm curious what events a user can see. From what I can tell, a user will see an event if:

- The event is assigned to them
- They are an invitee on the event

Are there any other situations where a user will see an event in their event list? (i.e. I noticed that just because *you* create an event, it doesn't mean you can see it on your event list)

Comment: There isn't a simple answer to your question. It first depends on whether or not roles are enabled. It then depends on the security model for contacts, accounts, opps, etc, ownership, opportunity teams, custom objects and many other things as to what someone will see. These things can be affected by sharing groups and record sharing as well. Its not a trivial question to answer and is very org dependant.

Comment: This link helps explain some of the sharing considerations: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_sharecal.htm&language=en_US