# Are security policies enforced on returned data from the API?

Tags: rest-api, security, permissions

I'm making an application that interacts with Salesforce Rest API. When logged in as a user, I can execute SOQL on behalf of that user, for example:

```
SELECT subject from event
```

However, this will return me all the events in existence, and will not enforce the same security policy that the Salesforce app itself uses. As mentioned in a comment on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/what-events-can-a-user-see-in-salesforce), when inquiring about which events are shown to a user:

> "It first depends on whether or not roles are enabled. It then depends
>   on the security model for contacts, accounts, opps, etc, ownership,
>   opportunity teams, custom objects and many other things as to what
>   someone will see. These things can be affected by sharing groups and
>   record sharing as well. "

How can I only show the Events (and not just events, but other objects) that Salesforce is showing the user based on security and permissions? Must I re-invent the wheel inside my application and manually check security settings, roles, profiles, groups, etc. to determine whether or not to show particular data to a user?

And what about field-level security? Must I check this too when editing an object via the Rest API?

Note: I've worked with other 3rd party application APIs that only return the data you can see based on your logged-in credentials. I'll be suprised if the burden is put on the data-caller.

Comment: A custom API call or the normal calls provided? Normal calls do enforce sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's a little weird...

In general, APEX REST methods are always invoked using System Mode...a.k.a. "God Mode".

Object and Field-Level Security **are not** enforced so the suggestion is to do some schema describes and determine yourself whether the requester has access to the object/fields/etc.

Sharing rules **are** enforced as long as you define your class using the `with sharing` keyword.

See here: [Exposing Data with Apex REST Web Service Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_exposing_data.htm)